# How to get field Type from View

Tags: 7, entities

I have a view that takes fields and combines them or compares them and then gives me results in a new field (views conditional, global text etc..) but I need the TYPE of data that is returned. How can I figure this out? I do not have Drush on my current setup or we'd be good to go... I looked in the DOM and see nothing special about the field for example...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Php views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) and in it  use [gettype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), I think you can acheive it by `Php views` ( also you can achieve it with [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)) and return data tye with `gettype`.

> gettype — Get the type of a variable Description
>
> string gettype (mixed $var )
>
> Returns the type of the PHP variable var.

Comment: I am not getting any results with this. I tried it in the content: custom php field. Should I be doing it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use `<?php dsm($fields) ?>` inside views-view-fields.tpl.php which you need to place inside the templates folder of your theme.

This will give the results similar to var_dump but in a much readable and organized format.